# Please explain use of 入る in this context

Tags: verbs

This is an excerpt from SAO - the context is that a character has suggested Kirito may be a spy. Leafa responds by saying:

> スパイにしてはちょっと天然{てんねん}ボケ入{はい}りすぎてるし

Not asking for a translation, as I already understand the meaning. But my feeling is that it is referring to Kirito as the subject and is saying he "contains" too much airheadedness? (I.e. he's too much of a dimwit) I basically just don't understand the use of 入る in this context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But my feeling is that it is referring to Kirito as the subject and is saying he "contains" too much airheadedness?

You've got the point. The nuance of 入る here is just like "is contained" or "is inside" as you understand, so that sentence reminds me while he "contains" too much airheadedness, he's not an absolute dimwit.

Although we don't often use 入る when describing the human's nature (e.g. 優しさが入ってる sounds weird), 天然 and 入る have a strong affinity because we can express euphemism by adding 入る.

Note that objectives may become subjectives if you translate 入る as "contains" especially in this context. You might as well consider it as "is inside". As a side note, "Intel Inside" was translated as "Intel 入ってる" in Japanese.